# Find the word from the list given and replace the words so found

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, any

My question is pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find a proper solution.
Given below is my program:

```
given_list   = ["Terms","I","want","to","remove","from","input_string"]
input_string = input("Enter String:")
if any(x in input_string for x in given_list):
     #Find the detected word
     #Not in bool format
     a = input_string.replace(detected_word,"")
     print("Some Task",a)
```

Here, **given_list** contains the terms I want to exclude from the **input_string**.
Now, the problem I am facing is that the any() produces a bool result and I need the word detected by the any() and replace it with a blank, so as to perform some task.

> **Edit:** any() function is not required at all, look for useful solutions below.

Comment: then you have to do the same loop like `[x for x in given_list if x in input_string]`

Comment: What if you have several words in the input?

Comment: If there are several words then I just want those terms removed, which are specified in the given_list @Dani Mesejo

Comment: By the way if you want words to be removed this approach wont work think for example if the word Illusion appears

Comment: do given list contains multitoken terms?

Comment: No the list doesn't contain multi-token terms @Dani Mesejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over given_list and replace them:

```
for i in given_list:
    input_string = input_string.replace(i, "")
print("Some Task", input_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to detect at all:

```
for w in given_list:
     input_string = input_string.replace(w, "")
```

`str.replace` will not do anything if the word is not there and the substring test needed for the detection has to scan the string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding each word and replacing it is that python will have to iterate over the whole string, repeatedly. Another problem is you will find substrings where you don't want to. For example, "to" is in the exclude list, so you'd end up changing "tomato" to "ma"

It seems to me like you seem to want to replace whole words. Parsing is a whole new subject, but let's simplify. I'm just going to assume everything is lowercase with no punctuation, although that can be improved later. Let's use input_string.split() to iterate over whole words.

We want to replace some words with nothing, so let's just iterate over the input_string, and filter out the words we don't want, using the builtin function of the same name.

```
exclude_list   = ["terms","i","want","to","remove","from","input_string"]
input_string = "one terms two i three want to remove"
keepers = filter(lambda w: w not in exclude_list, input_string.lower().split())
output_string = ' '.join(keepers)
print (output_string)
```

> one two three

Note that we create an iterator that allows us to go through the whole input string just once. And instead of replacing words, we just basically skip the ones we don't want by having the iterator not return them.

Since filter requires a function for the boolean check on whether to include or exclude each word, we had to define one. I used "lambda" syntax to do that. You could just replace it with

```
def keep(word):
    return word not in exclude_list

keepers = filter(keep, input_string.split())
```

Comment: Thank you @Kenny Ostrom. But I am fairly new to Python and do not know what is lambda syntax. I used a simpler method (as provided by @BTables)as the work I am doing is of beginner level.

Comment: You can just define a function, instead of lambda.

Comment: I have started python programming a few days back and do not know how to define a  function. @Kenny Ostrom

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about `any`, use an assignment expression (Python 3.8+).

```
if any((word := x) in input_string for x in given_list):
    # match captured in variable word
```